# Integrate Strava with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, integration, strava

I would like to integrate Strava(sport tracking application/platform) with google Sheets, specifically I would like to update a google sheet spreadsheet when I upload an activity in Strava. There is some that can tell me what I was to do or where do I have to seek to learn to do it? Thank you in advance!

ps. The next step will be integrate Xiaomi Mi fit with google Sheet to compile the same spreadsheet, but I think that the tools are the same or at least almost...

Comment: this is a good starting point: http://developers.strava.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable coding and working with REST API's, you could register for a developer account at Strava (https://developers.strava.com/) and implement this feature in your language/platform of choice.  However, I would recommend starting with a much simple solution.

Check out Zapier (https://zapier.com/).  Zapier lets you connect apps to build new functionality without writing a single line of code.  It looks like Zapier has a Strava to Google Sheet integration, which is probably the quickest way for you to get started.  Zapier is super simple, and offers tons of cool functionality.

Good luck!